# problems with array unique

Tags: php

I'm trying to figure out how a way to check for duplicates in an array, but the following code is not giving the desired result:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
              for ($j = 0; $j < count($ships[$i][0]); $j++) {
                        if ($hitX.$hitY === $ships[$i][1][$j].$ships[$i][0][$j]) {
                            echo("hit");
                            array_push( $ships[$i]["hits"], array($hitX,$hitY));
                            $ships[$i]["hits"] = array_unique($ships[$i]["hits"])
```

For example, I want to reduce the following array so that it only contains unique values:

```
[hits] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => k
                [1] => 6
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => j
                [1] => 6
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [0] => j
                [1] => 6
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [0] => j
                [1] => 6
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [0] => j
                [1] => 6
            )

    )
```

)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
$ships[$i]["hits"] = array_unique($ships[$i]["hits"], SORT_REGULAR);
```